# UWP Alinhamento horizontal dos flhos em um RelativePanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Estou criando um HambugerMenu similar aos dos Apps Win10. A base do HambugerMenu é o `SplitView` e para distribuir os filhos no `SplitView` optei por usar um `RelativePanel` assim posso escolher quais itens do menu ficarão na parte de cima e quais ficarão na parte de baixo do menu, do mesmo modo que acontece no App Clima, onde as opções principais do menu ficam na parte de cima e as de menor importância na parte de baixo, como por exemplo, o item configurações e de informações do usuário.
Porém, não estou conseguindo que os itens da parte de baixo tenham o mesmo preenchimento/alinhamento dos de cima, como pode ser visto na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei várias coisas, coloquei `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, fiz binding para fazer o `ListView` de baixo usar o mesmo tamanho do `ListView` de cima, mas nada adiantou. O `ListView` inferior simplesmente ignora qualquer configuração que o faça aumentar de forma não fixa.

Segue o [XAML](http://pastebin.com/DpuT3Cnh)

Comment: Salvo engando esse componente faz a mesma coisa que você está tentando fazer manualmente: https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit | http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/HamburgerMenu/

Comment: Pois é tem muita coisa legal já implementada, mas eu quero limitar ao máximo o número de dependências.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a resposta no [fórum MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/321b52ed-57be-4505-adcd-922a71e3b181/listview-fill-in-relativepanel?forum=wpdevelop).
Na prática ele implementa via code-behind o que deveria funcionar via XAML bindings mas não funciona. Por que raios, eu não sei.